# Avatar not display after adding route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, haml, ruby-on-rails-6

I added this route to redirect every invalid URL to root route.

```
match '*path' => redirect { |_p, req|
                     req.flash[:alert] = I18n.t('routes.no_page')
                     '/'
                   }, via: :get
```

After some time I discovered that the avatar does not display, nor can I change it. I started looking for the cause and found that after commenting out the above route, the avatar started displaying correctly. I'm using Active Storage to store avatars on Amazon server.

Comment: The `'*path'` route catches all paths and therefore shadows all later route definitions in the file. Where did you define the route for the avatar? Perhaps just try moving its definition above the '*path' definition?

Comment: what is "the avatar"?

Comment: Do not do this. You're just giving yourself a huge headache with this catch-all as your tests will not tell you if you have a routing error. Instead use`config.exceptions_app` to handle the routing error. https://web-crunch.com/posts/custom-error-page-ruby-on-rails